# Problemas con mi consulta select y con la add_moths

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Amigos, espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, tengo el siguiente problema con esta consulta, lo que pasa es que quiero traerme los registros que una fecha en especifico hacía atras, por ejm, tengo un registro en la tabla de parametros que sería esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa consulta la estoy metiendo en mi siguiente consulta principal que sería la siguiente:

```
   SELECT cta_que_factura, tipo_documento,id_estatus, uuid, FECHA_CREACION, NOM_SISTEMA
    from complemento_pago
        where tipo_documento =4 and id_estatus =6 AND UUID IS NULL
            and cta_que_factura in (1101810003, 110034600)
            and FECHA_CREACION >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'dd'),-(select valor from parametros where ID_PARAMETRO =334))
            and FECHA_CREACION <  trunc(sysdate,'dd')
```

Pero hay algo mal, que no me trae los dias anteriores es decir, siempre me trae **18/07/20**
Hay algo que estoy haciendo mal, o si es por la función **add_months** que no soporta lo que estoy haciendo?

Espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, si hay algo que no se entienda con gusto les aclaro sus dudas. Quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios. Saludos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya que no son los que está recuperando, ¿Qué datos esperas que traiga la consulta?

Comment: Hola buenas noches, espero que me regrese los dias anteriores, es decir, si en el registro  está 18/07/20, que me regrese 11/07/20, no se si me dé a entender?

Comment: Según veo, debiera traerlos, probablemente no haya datos en la tabla subyacente.

Comment: Ya validé la información y si la hay, desconozco por que mi consulta no lo trae, mira asi es como la tengo actualmente: SELECT cta_que_factura, tipo_documento,id_estatus, uuid, FECHA_CREACION, NOM_SISTEMA
    from complemento_pago
        where tipo_documento =4 and id_estatus =6 AND UUID IS NULL 
            and (FECHA_CREACION >=  TO_DATE(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/YY')-(select valor from parametros where ID_PARAMETRO =334))  
            and nom_sistema = Upper((select valor from parametros where id_parametro =335));
Pero el problema que no me resta los dias

Comment: No pongas una consulta completa en comentarios, si es distinta a la de la pregunta, colocala allí. Has hecho la prueba básica de hacer solamente el `select` que resta el valor de la tabla de parámetros?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo estas intentado retroceder 7 meses atrás en tu consulta, estas seguro que tienes esos datos en tu tabla con ese intervalo de fechas?.

Ademas veo que tus rangos limites están fijos en tu consulta, 7 meses atrás y a la fecha actual del sistema, comprueba que valores te están dando y si la fecha del sistema esta correcta:

```
select add_months(trunc(sysdate,'dd'),-(select valor from parametros where ID_PARAMETRO =334)) FROM DUAL;
```

```
select trunc(sysdate,'dd') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias amigo, es parecida tu solución a la mia, solo que en mi caso metí la función TO_DATE(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/YY'), en si, son 7 dias o mas, depende cuando si en un momento quieran cambiar mas atrás los dias, ya solo vallan al campo valor actualicen los dias, mas abajo puse mi solución, saludos

Answer (score 0):

si logré terminarlo, aqui les dejo mi solución para quien le pudiese servir:

```
SELECT cta_que_factura, tipo_documento,id_estatus, uuid, FECHA_CREACION, NOM_SISTEMA
    from complemento_pago
        where tipo_documento =4 and id_estatus =6 AND UUID IS NULL and  cta_que_factura = 1100346001
            and FECHA_CREACION >=  TO_DATE(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/YY')-(select valor from parametros where ID_PARAMETRO =334)                              
            and nom_sistema = Upper((select valor from parametros where id_parametro =335));
```

Muchas gracias a todos los que se molestaron en brindarme sus soluciones, saludos y excelente día.